# Google Map Base Layer can't display in IE

Tags: google-maps

This is my code to new a google map after sliding to the div that displaying the map:

```
!self.map  &&  (self.map    = new google.maps.Map(self.$map[0], {
                            center : self.location,
                    zoom   : 15,
                    streetViewControl:false,
                    scrollwheel:false,
                            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }));
```

The base 2D tiles is transparent in IE8
[image: IE8]

but not in FF, Safari and Chrome
[image: Safari]

Answer (score 0):

my suggestion

- is "self.$map[0]" is normal html node not jquery object or whatever?
- try give it the node id
- element should be visible on init.
- give it fixed height